# Join Personal Hotspot automatically? Never works

Tags: macos, tethering, continuity, wifi, cellular-data

So I have my iPhone working as a **Personal Hotspot**.

In System Settings > Wi-Fi, it shows in the Personal Hotspot section. I can connect to it with a click.

In its settings (both via Details or through three-dots-in-a-circle menu > Network Settings) it says, **Automatically Join This Network**.

It even says, **Auto-Join** in that menu.

[image: Settings]

So why do I always need to **click Join** notification when I open my laptop (and sometimes after a minute of waiting, but that's a different story)?

[image: Click to Join]

Has someone succeeded in reconnecting to PH automagically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The setting you are looking at, "Join Automatically" only applies when the network is visible. The personal hotspot is off by default so it cannot join it automatically.

The only setting available on macOS is "Ask to join hotspots" which presents the notification you have indicated. The hotspot will stay on and available so long as one device is connected to it, then the phone shuts it down to preserve battery and you must re-join using that notification (which enables the hotspot, then joins it.)

Comment: In a way, I should try to turn this off so it's not asking me and just connect to those marked as Auto-join, please!

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth on the MacBook should be also turned on.
In the iPhone Settings -> Personal Hotspot - uncheck "Maximise Compatibility"

Comment: I have BT on both devices and yes, I don't need to use Maximise Compatibility as I do not have any older devices around.

Answer (score 0):

> Has someone succeeded in reconnecting to PH automagically?

Connecting “automagically” is not a good idea.  Joining a Hotspot means you’re connecting to a *metered* connection.  Maybe you want to connect this time, but what if you don’t and instead want to the WiFi you have access to (i.e. “guest” SSID)?

By automatically connecting, your laptop will always make a connection when the two devices are within proximity - you could end up with data overage.  Remember carriers may say “unlimited data” but that doesn’t mean they don’t throttle speed once you cross a certain threshold.

Bottom line:  asking you to join a hotspot is a safety chech of sorts ensuring you’re connecting to the appropriate netwrk and not oversubscribed your data plan.

Comment: macOS isn't that babysitting. If I really want to force delete root recursively, I can. So I should be able to auto connect to my unlimited connection (with FUP of 100 GB). And I could always tick "Low data mode" if I want to prevent i.e. downloading updates.